# Java 8 LocalDate- determining the year of a yearless Feb-29 date?

Tags: java, date, java-8, jodatime

My colleague and I have an interesting problem. We work with an old system that only returns date data in the format `ddMMM`. If the day/month is in the past for the current year, then we are to assume this date applies to next year. Otherwise it applies to the current year.

So today is `4/30/2015`. If the system returned records with `12MAR`, then that date translates to `3/12/2016`. If the date reads `07MAY`, then it translates to `5/7/2015`.

However, it is unclear how to determine the year for `29FEB` since it is a leap year. We cannot instantiate it with a year without the possibility of it throwing an error. We relied on a `try/catch` when trying to create a `LocalDate` off it for the current year. If it catches, we assume it belongs to next year.

Is there a more kosher way to do this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

- Parse the value as a `MonthDay`, as that's what you've got.
- If the month-day is *not* February 29th, just handle it as normal
- If it *is* February 29th, you need to special-case it:

  - Determine whether the current year is a leap year with [`Year.isLeap(long)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Year.html#isLeap-long-)
  - If it is:
  - If it's currently on or before Feb 29th, then the result is Feb 29th of this year
  - If it's currently *after* Feb 29th, you need rules to apply - you could choose March 1st of next year or Feb 28th of next year
  - If it's not (a leap year this year)
  - If it's currently on or before Feb 28th, again you need to rules to apply, probably returning March 1st or Feb 28th of this year
  - If it's currently *after* Feb 28th, then the date logically belongs to next year...

    - If next year is a leap year, the result is presumably Feb 29th of next year
    - If next year is *not* a leap year, again you need a rule

That's hopefully outlined the three "odd" conditions you need to account for - we don't have enough information to tell you what to do in those conditions.

Answer (score 3):

## java.time

The modern way is with the java.time classes. Specifically, [`MonthDay`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/MonthDay.html) in your case.

Note that you should always specify a [`Locale`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Locale.html) to determine the human language to use in translation of name of month.

```
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "ddMMM" , Locale.ENGLISH );

String input = "29FEB";
MonthDay md = MonthDay.parse( input , f );
```

You can apply this to a year to get a [`LocalDate`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html) object, a date-only value of year-month-day.

## `LocalDate`

The [`LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html) class represents a date-only value without time-of-day and without time zone.

A time zone is crucial in determining a date. For any given moment, the date varies around the globe by zone. For example, a few minutes after midnight in [Paris France](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Europe/Paris) is a new day while still “yesterday” in [Montréal Québec](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/America/Montreal).

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" );
LocalDate today = LocalDate.now( z );
```

If we are looking at February 29, check for Leap Year. If this is not a Leap Year, then you said you want to move to next year. But what if next year is also not a Leap Year? You need to keep going until you reach a Leap Year.

```
int yearNumber today.getYear();
LocalDate ld = null;
if( md.equals( MonthDay.of( 2 , 29 )  && ( ! Year.of( today ).isLeap() ) ) { 
    // If asking for February 29, and this is not a leap year, move to next year, per our business rule.
    … keep adding years until you find a year that *is* a leap year.
    ld = md.atYear( yearNumber + x ); 
} else {
    ld = md.atYear( yearNumber );
}
```

### Fall back to 28th

This Question had a special business rule about jumping to the following year if the month-day is February 29 in a non-Leap Year. But for other folks be aware the default behavior in java.time is to simply fall back to February 28 when asking for the 29th a non-Leap Year. No exception is thrown.

```
LocalDate february28 = 
    MonthDay.of( 2 , 29 )
            .atYear( myNonLeapYearNumber );  // 29th becomes 28th.
```

---

## About java.time

The [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`java.text.SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to java.time.

To learn more, see the [Oracle Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8) and [**SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9) and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - The [*ThreeTenABP*](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts ***ThreeTen-Backport*** (mentioned above) for Android specifically.
  - See [*How to use…*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [ThreeTen-Extra](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).